# Use Sass @content and unify parent selector to immediate child selector

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to use Sass / SCSS to unify the @content directive to the parent class. I am attempting to use a conditional statement within the mixin to allow for both use cases:

```
$themes: (
    Light: (
        page_background: #ffffff,
    ),
    Dark: (
        page_background: #181818,
    )
);

@function get_color($key) {
    @return map-get($theme-map, $key);
}

@mixin theme($makeAncestor: true) {
    @each $theme, $map in $themes {
        $theme-map: $map !global;

        @if $makeAncestor {
            .#{$theme} & {
                @content;
            }
        } @else {
            .#{$theme} & {
                @content;
            }
        }
    }
    $theme-map: null !global;
}

.fixed {
    @include theme() {
        background: get_color(page_background);
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
.Light .fixed {
     background: #ffffff;
}
```

Desired output:

```
.Light.fixed {
     background: #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`@at-root`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/at-root) in your mixin and interpolate the parent selector:

```
@mixin theme($makeAncestor: true) {
   @at-root {
      @each $theme, $map in $themes {
         $theme-map: $map !global;
    
         @if $makeAncestor {
            .#{$theme}#{&} {
               @content;
            }
          } @else {
            .#{$theme}#{&} {
               @content;
            }
          }
       }
      $theme-map: null !global;
   }
}
```